# How to upload image robot framework?

Tags: selenium, automation, robotframework

Im trying to upload image but i cant. The error message : element not interactable.
How can I solve this problem.

```
*** Variables ***
${b}  chrome
${url}           https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-automation
${username}      id:username
${password}      id:password
${login}         class:applynow
${btn_checkbox}  id:tried-ecom
${submit}        id:submit-button
${upload_image}  id:img
${image_path}    \Users\user\PycharmProjects\LambdaTestCertificate\TestCase\jenkins.svg


*** Test Cases ***
Test title
    open browser  https://www.lambdatest.com/automation-demos/  ${b}
    maximize browser window
    sleep  1  seconds
    input text  ${username}  lambda
    input password  ${password}  lambda123
    click element  ${login}
    sleep  2  seconds
    select checkbox  ${btn_checkbox}
    sleep  2 seconds
    SeleniumLibrary.mouse down  ${submit}
    sleep  2 seconds
    choose file  ${upload_image}  \\Users\\user\\Downloads\\jenkins.svg
    sleep  2 seconds
```

Comment: Your locator points to label. Try `id:file`

Comment: @JaPyR Thank you sir.